# How to record text-to-speech in OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, recording, text-to-speech

When using the `say` command to speak text in OS X, how can the output be sent to a file so that it can be played back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the command line:

```
$ say -o hello.aiff 'hello world'
$ say -o output.aiff -f input.txt
```